# Nginx proxy to text to speech enigne

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been trying my luck at using Nginx as a reverse proxy to a text-to-speach engine

I Work with humanoid social robots that run a quite old operating system and software, their build in Text to speach engine is limited in language support and as such we use an external service to have them talk.

Now the service we i'm using will end support for http connections by the end of the year. The robots software only supports http audio streams because of its horibly outdated software and certificates. As such i thought to set up a simple http to https proxy using Nginx.

However i'm getting an error after the service redirects the request to a page with a different url and protocol

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 8008;

        location /tts {
                proxy_pass https://tts.readspeaker.com/a/speak;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
        }

        location @handle_redirect {
                resolver 8.8.8.8;
                proxy_pass '$upstream_http_location';
        }
}
```

Error recieved:
`2023/12/04 09:55:35 [error] 6038#6038: *2 invalid URL prefix in "" while sending to client, client: 217.67.224.106, server: , request: "GET /tts?key=notarealkey&lang=de_de&voice=Max&text=schnitzel&streaming=1&volume=200&speed=80&pitch=110 HTTP/1.1", host: "not.realhost.nl:8008`

The external server accepts the initial request and retuns a redirect to an mp3 file that can be streamed for instance:

`https://rstts.readspeaker.com/cgi-bin/rspeak/d320a54c54cc486d4babff4edf3ab17e.mp3`

Now i want my proxy to handle the redirect and respond with the streamable mp3 file.

Maybe this doesn't work for streamable resources? or some headers are missing?

Replacing the `proxy_pass '$upstream_http_location';` with `return 200 '$upstream_http_location'` does return the correct full url to the stream